# Magento - Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, magento

Sometimes, when we place an order in the backend - with a NEW customer, we get the following error upon submitting it:

```
Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
`artizara_artizara/enterprise_reward`, CONSTRAINT `FK_REWARD_CUSTOMER_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES customer_entity` (`entity_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I've looked up the error log and it says the following:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint 
violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`artizara_artizara/enterprise_reward`, CONSTRAINT `FK_REWARD_CUSTOMER_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in /chroot/home/artizara/artizara.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

I've researched this in google/Magento forums and some people say it has to do with the table not being InnobDB...

So I went into phpMyAdmin and pulled up the `enterprise_reward` table. Opened the **Operations** tab. Next to **Storage Engine** it says InnoDB so I think I'm set there...

Other people tried making sql statements for their issue by searching for orphan data. I'm not quite sure what this is looking for exactly so I don't know how to put the sql statement together (I'm a bit newer at that anyway).

Will someone please help figure this out (making by searching for the orphan data, etc) and perhaps let me know why this has happened in the first place?

FYI - they can't give me a clear picture as to whether this happens with EVERY new customer (when placing an order in the admin) or just sometimes - so I don't have that info (yet)...

***Edit 5/16 @ 2:30p:***

I've tried looking for orphans with this sql code but **no results returned**...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  enterprise_reward
LEFT
  JOIN
    customer_entity
    ON enterprise_reward.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id
WHERE
  customer_entity.entity_id IS NULL
```

Comment: If you are using Enterprise edition I would recommend submitting a support ticket with Varien. Not that somebody here won't help you, but support is part of what you are paying for.

Comment: Incidentially I think what is happening is that the system is trying to give a reward to a customer, before the customer is created in the system.

Comment: http://seanbreeden.com/post/14693198343/fk-reward-customer-id-foreign-key-error-in-magento may help, but advise against editing core directly and just move into local instead.

Comment: @JoshPennington - We are on Magento Pro ver. 1.10.1.0 (with some Enterprise features added on), which is now phased out. We don't have support. I do think along the same lines of what you're thinking though and thats why I asked here b/c I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @B00MER - I think I've seen this fix and it didn't work for me. I'm going to give it another go...

Comment: Have you tried disabling rewards on the site to see if that fixes the problem? Obviously this does not fix your problem, but will at least confirm that the problem is in the rewards system.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "with a few Enterprise features thrown in"? Did you take the professional edition and just throw in some of the enterprise code?

Comment: @JoshPennington I haven't been able to duplicate this issue on our dev site yet so I haven't been able to test that theory. I'm trying to get more information as to what the customer is ordering, etc so that I can incorporate that in my tests...

What I mean by (Enterprise features...) is that, before my time here, an ex-Varien developer took our Magento Pro and added on some some of the Enterprise features/modules to our Pro version. I think it had to do with the Rewards, Customer Credits & Gift Cards but I'm not entirely sure of everything he's added...

Answer (score 0):

We are indeed experiencing this same issue on enterprise 1.10.0.1.  This appears to be a known bug that has been filed with Varien.  However - I have not found a solution.

Best thing I could find is this thread:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/234872

The bug report I found is posted below.

BUG ID:  26516
Posted:  2011-09-21 15:22:18

When payment processing fails with an exception, the following error occurs in certain situations:

> Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`magento_enterprise`.`enterprise_reward`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_REWARD_CUSTOMER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES
>   `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
./lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
./lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php:300
./lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:479
./lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:238
./lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:333
./lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:574
./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php:414
./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:318
./app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Reward.php:202
./app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Observer.php:548
./app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Observer.php:564
./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1265
./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1246
./app/Mage.php:416
./app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php:187
./app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php:126
./EnterpriseRewardTest.php:70
```

Steps to reproduce:

- use Magento Enterprise with Enterprise Rewards enabled (or another
  module with a similar code, see below)
- use a payment module that supports on-line authorization
- check out an order as a new customer
- trigger a payment error (e.g. by entering an invalid CC no).

I attached a PHPUnit test case that should reproduce the problem reliably.

The culprit is the code in Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder that does the following:

1. start a transaction
2. build a new order
3. create a new customer and fill in the order's customerId field
4. attempt to process the order, which raises an exception
5. roll back the transaction
6. dispatch "quote_submit_failure" event using the order as event data. Note that the order's customerId field now contains an invalid value since the transaction has been rolled back.

Now, if a handler for quote_submit_failure proceeds to use order's customerId, it will necessarily trigger the aforementioned "integrity constraint violation" error.

The problem can be reproduced on following versions:
- Magento Enterprise Edition v1.10.0.1
- Magento Community Edition v1.6.0.0 (provided there happens to be a quote_submit_failure handler that expect a valid customerId.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add **$this->_stmt->queryString** to Zend_Db_Statement_Exception at lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php (_execute method) to see what query is throwing the error.

It will be something like..

> ```
> throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($e->getMessage() . $this->_stmt->queryString, (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
> ```

**But remember: do not commit core modifications in Magento. It's not cool.**

Source: [Aftab Naveed's Blog](http://aftabnaveed.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/magento-display-full-query-in-the-exception/)

Answer (score 0):

If using 1.10.0.1 or less, patch this file `app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Observer.php` by adding a check for customer id

```
protected function _revertRewardPointsForOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    // Patch for known 1.10.0.1 bug
    if (!$order->getCustomer()->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }
    // End patch
    Mage::getModel('enterprise_reward/reward')
        ->setCustomerId($order->getCustomerId())
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId())
        ->setPointsDelta($order->getRewardPointsBalance())
        ->setAction(Enterprise_Reward_Model_Reward::REWARD_ACTION_REVERT)
        ->setActionEntity($order)
        ->updateRewardPoints();

    return $this;
}
```